# Footer won't hide on smaller screens

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm working on a technical documentation page for Javascript for a project and my footer using media queries doesn't hide on small screens like I'd want it to.

Things tried:

- changing position fixed, this resulted in the footer vanishing completely
- display: none;
- height and width set to 0px;

Here's my SASS code, it's linked correctly to the html page and CSS.

```css
footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:400px) {

    footer {
        display:none;

    }
}
```

```html
<footer>
        Designed and Coded by: 
        <a href="what i linked" target="_blank">my name</a>
    </footer>
```

I assume it's something quite simple I'm missing but I'm a newbie so thought I'd ask for a hand.

Thank you very much, appreciate your time.

Comment: Is that media query the last instance of styling your footer?

Comment: That it is, I moved it to the beginning just then but no difference when I checked the small screen size.

Comment: remove the only word from your css code.

 @media screen and (max-width:400px) {

            footer {
                display:none;
            }
        }

Comment: @Mehrwarz, there is no difference between if add the `only` or not

Comment: I am using Edge browser with Firefox. removing the only makes it working.

Comment: @Mehrwarz, well, if that is true ignore my comment. In chrome, it seems the same and doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think james answer is a good solution, but I also wanted to ask a thing.
What is a small screen for you, a screen with less than `400px` width then please ignore this, but if it is a screen with less than `400px` height then  change to this:

```css
@media only screen and (max-height:400px) {
    footer {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Note: It will be `max-height` instead of `max-width`.

Answer (score 1):

Add `<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />` before it will work for you.

```css
    footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:400px) {
    footer {
        display:none;

    }
}
```

```html
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />

    <footer>
        Designed and Coded by: 
        <a href="what i linked" target="_blank">my name</a>
    </footer>
```

Photo:[image]

Comment: I removed my link and full name before posting for privacy, but they were correctly integrated. "what i linked" and "my name" were placeholders for what was actually there if I wasn't clear, apologies.

Answer (score 1):

```
Use in head tag: 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

In CSS:
@media only screen and (max-width:400px) {
    footer {
        position: unset;
        display: none;

    }
}
```

Comment: How is this different from my answer?